# Can somebody explain parameters in run.conf of JBoss AS

Tags: jboss5.x

In run.conf of JBoss AS there are few parameters which I am unable to figure out how they are used MAX_FD, PROFILER, JAVA_HOME, JAVA. Can somebody explain the use of these parameters. I agree I am new to JBoss and these are preliminary questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this wiki entry](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossRunParameters)

- **JAVA_HOME** : The location of the JDK (java development kit)
- **JAVA_OPTS** : Options passed the java command, e.g. -Xmx512M
- **JAVA** : The name of the java binary (default java)
- **JBOSS_CLASSPATH** : additional classpath entries, if this is set, its value will be prepended to the classpath at startup
- **MAX_FD** : The maximum number of file descriptors used by JBoss (Unix only)

Comment: Yes you are right. I also read this in the documentation but I have following doubts 1. MAX_FD : The maximum number of file descriptors used by JBoss (Unix only) - what does this mean?

Comment: JAVA_HOME - I deleted the JAVA_HOME environment variable and set the JAVA_HOME in run.conf but the server did not start up. JAVA - The name of the java binary -what does this mean?

Comment: File descriptor is a Unix file reference. Basically, this parameter tells how many files/sockets/devices JBoss may open at once. About the `JAVA_HOME`: to what value did you set it? `JAVA` probably refers to the `java` executable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I set it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java \jdk1.6.0_20 which is same as the value set in environment variable. I do not know if the issue is because of the space after Program and Files but then it should not work even with environment variables.

Comment: When you start JBoss, it shows the values for some of these variables (I don't remember exactly which, but I'm almost sure that at least `JAVA_HOME` is shown). Could you start JBoss before without overriding the variables? If you could, what values did it use?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Xms is for defining minimum memory size that is to be allocated for the deployed jboss Appplication  and Xmx is maximum memory size.If any exception like "Out of Memory" we should increase this memory size for the application from this run.conf file.

That is increase the range of Xms - Xmx value